# Tomcat JNDI connection behavior differs from JDBC connection

Tags: tomcat, stored-procedures, jdbc, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a Tomcat 7 web application using the jt400 JDBC driver connecting to DB2 running on an iSeries V6R1. I've been using this same setup for years with little problem. Using the JNDI connection set up in my context.xml and the driver in my WEB-INF/lib folder everything works as expected, JPA queries and everything else.

I am now attempting to use a stored procedure which calls an RPG program. When I use the JNDI connection, it errors saying it cannot find the external program. If I create a new JDBC connection using the exact same (copied and pasted) connection string, driver, username and password, it works perfectly. The same stored procedure also works perfectly when run from SQuirreL.

Using the JNDI connection I get the following error:

```
[SQL0444] External program xxx in *LIBL not found
```

Here is my (sanitized) connection string:

```
jdbc:as400:server;naming=system;prompt=false;datetime=iso;libraries=SYSIBM OTHER LIBS AS NEEDED
```

Here is my code:

```
        CallableStatement cs=null;
        // Fails every time
        // Connection conn = getJNDIConnection();
        // Works every time
        Connection conn = getNewJDBCConnection();
        cs = conn.prepareCall("CALL MY_PROC (  0, 'TEST' )");
        cs.execute();
```

I really would love to rely on the JNDI connection rather than creating my own, but I will have to use that workaround unless someone has a clue as to what is causing this error.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

*LIBL is a clue here.  What sets the JNDI connection's library list?

Another place to look is the signature.  When you CALL the stored procedure via JNDI, are you using the exact same argument types and lengths as when you use SQuirreL?  In particular, be aware of the difference between a CHAR parameter and a VARCHAR parameter.

Comment: I'm using the exact same SQL, I copied and pasted it from SQuirreL as a matter of fact. I did that to eliminate any possibility of type mismatches, etc. I'll add the code to my post to make it easier to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Sorry, the connection string itself sets the library list. Note I'm using system naming and specifying a list of libraries. I regularly use stored procedures, and this isn't even the first one that calls an RPG program.

Comment: There is no library list 'other libs as needed' - JNDI is doing some sort of work under the covers to turn that into an actual list of libraries.  It sounds as if it hasn't included the library where the RPG program object is.  Try making a specific library list.

Comment: I just threw in that line for security concerns, the actual list is correct and works just fine with all of my queries except this stored procedure, but the same connection string from a non-JNDI connection works just fine.

Comment: Can you post the CREATE PROCEDURE statement you used?

Comment: I didn't create it myself, but I can use it from a straight jdbc connection, just not the jndi connection which is using the same connection info.